# How would I go about showing that f is one-to-one?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How would I go about showing that f is one-to-one? (Excuse the image link, I am not savvy enough to use mathematical symbols on here!)

> Define $f: \mathbb R \setminus\{-\frac{3}{2}\}\to \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}$ by $f(x) = \dfrac{x+5}{2x+3}$. (You may assume without proving it that $\dfrac{x+5}{2x+3} \neq \dfrac{1}{2}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{-\frac{3}{2}\}.)$

Comment: I edited your question so it is now readable directly. Please remember that you will be expected to know the basics of MathJax if you continue to post questions here. You can always check what I did in the edit to this post to see how to write basic symbols, and for a more detailed list, see the mathjax tutorial:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1

Comment: S.B. posted a response that fully answered your question. Is there any reason why you have not accepted the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options, which are almost the same
We can pick $f(x)=f(y)$ and prove that $x=y$ follows, or pick $x\neq y$ and prove that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ follows

In your case, $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow (x+5)(2y+3)=(y+5)(2x+3)\Rightarrow 2xy+3x+10y+15=2xy+10x+3y+15\Rightarrow 7x=7y \Rightarrow x=y$

Therefor the function is one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

One way is to plot the graph and then draw a line parallel to X axis, if line touches the graph only at **one point** then it is one-one function

[image]

If the line passes through more than one point then it will be many-one function.

[image]

Comment: That is not a proof. That is a visualization.

Comment: @5xum I thought the question was to show that the function is one one, so we can saw by plotting graph

Comment: "showing" something is a mathematical synonim for proving something. And a picture is almost never a proof in mathematics. Proofs are more strict.